# NestJs cannot istantiate module (circular dependencies error?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have two modules which depend on each other.

GameModule.ts

```
import { Module, CacheModule, Global } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GameController } from './game.controller';
import { GameService } from './game.service';
import { PlayerModule } from '@src/player/player.module';

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    CacheModule.register(),
    PlayerModule,
  ],
  controllers: [GameController],
  providers: [GameService],
  exports: [CacheModule, GameService],
})
export class GameModule {}
```

PlayerModule.ts

```
import { Module, Global } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PlayerController } from './player.controller';
import { PlayerService } from './player.service';
import { GameModule } from '@src/game/game.module';
import { Web3ManagerModule } from '@src/web3-manager/web3-manager.module';

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [GameModule, Web3ManagerModule],
  controllers: [PlayerController],
  providers: [PlayerService],
  exports: [PlayerService],
})
export class PlayerModule {}
```

I defined in their services the other one with forwardRef

GameService.ts

```
...
constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => PlayerService))
    private playerService: PlayerService,
  ) {
...
```

PlayerService.ts

```
...
constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => GameService))
    private gameService: GameService,
    private web3Manager: Web3ManagerService,
  ) {
...
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
Nest cannot create the GameModule instance.
The module at index [1] of the GameModule "imports" array is undefined.
Potential causes:
- A circular dependency between modules. Use forwardRef() to avoid it. Read more: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency
- The module at index [1] is of type "undefined". Check your import statements and the type of the module.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Need forwardRef in module too. But I do not recommend using forwardRef, that's a mess, try to refactor common function to another service file

Comment: Sadly its a code I just inherited from other devs so I still need to figure out how it works. About the forwardRef, do I have to put on the same dependencies in the module? An example would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: imports: [forwardRef(() =>GameModule), Web3ManagerModule], here it is. Using same as in GameModule too